# Removing focus from spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner, autofill

I wish to create a search function where i have a edit-text and i have placed a spinner below it. When i type anything in the edittext, there is a array from which i compare the letters typed in the edittext and after filtering the array elements i add them into the spinner and open the spinner.

the problem i am facing is that when the spinner is opened the edittext looses focus and i need to close the spinner to start typing again.

i am attaching the code please anyone who has any idea please help me :

layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

       android:orientation="vertical"

        >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            />
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/edit_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editText;
    Spinner spinner;
    ArrayList<String> mylist;
    String[] strngarray;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mylist = new ArrayList<>();
        strngarray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
        for(int i=0;i<strngarray.length;i++)
        {
            mylist.add(strngarray[i]);

        }

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.edit_spinner);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,(List)mylist);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                Log.d("TextWatcher","before changed Char : "+s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                Log.d("TextWatcher", "on changed Char : " + s);
if(!s.equals("")) {

    mylist.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < strngarray.length; i++) {
        String temp = strngarray[i].toLowerCase();
        String prefix = s.toString().toLowerCase();
        if (temp.startsWith(prefix)) {
            mylist.add(strngarray[i]);
        }

    }
    if (mylist.size() != 0) {
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, (List) mylist);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        spinner.performClick();
        spinner.clearFocus();
        editText.requestFocus();
    }
}
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                Log.d("TextWatcher","after changed Char : "+s);
            }
        });

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a TextView and a Spinner you can implement AutoCompleteTextView.

This allows suggestions as the user is typing.
 You can bind the data to be searched for, using Adapters.

An example that might be helpful can be found [here.](http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/11/android-autocompletetextview-sqlite-and-dependent-fields/)